Having Header Already sent Issues
I was trying to download a file using the res.download of express. The file is downloading but i keep getting header already sent and the server crashes
const getRequestTemplate = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        // Call the service function to get the file path
        const filePath = await getRequestTemplateService();
        
        // Send the file as a response
        res.download(filePath, 'requestTemplate.xlsx', (err) => {
            if (err) {
                // Handle errors here
                console.error('Error downloading file:', err);
                res.status(400).json({ statusCode: 400, message: 'Error Downloading Request Template', data: null });
            } else {
                // Send success response if download completes successfully
                console.log('File downloaded successfully');
                // You can send any custom success response here
                res.status(200).json({ statusCode: 200, message: 'Request Template downloaded successfully', data: null });
            }
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error:', error);
        res.status(500).json({ statusCode: 500, message: 'Error Downloading Request Template', data: null });
    }
}


const getRequestTemplate = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        // Call the service function to get the file path
        const filePath = await getRequestTemplateService();
        
        // Send the file as a response
        res.download(filePath, 'requestTemplate.xlsx', (err) => {
            if (err) {
                // Handle errors here
                console.error('Error downloading file:', err);
                if (!res.headersSent) { // Check if headers are already sent
                    res.status(400).json({ statusCode: 400, message: 'Error Downloading Request Template', data: null });
                }
            } else {
                // Send success response if download completes successfully
                console.log('File downloaded successfully');
                // Note: Do not send response here as it may conflict with the file download
            }
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error:', error);
        res.status(500).json({ statusCode: 500, message: 'Error Downloading Request Template', data: null });
    }
}

In this code, we moved the calls to res.status and res.json outside of the res.download callback function to send the success status code when the download completes. So now, we don't resend the headers when the file download is successful, avoiding the 'header already sent' error. Also, if there's an error during the download and headers are already sent, we don't send an extra error status code. That way, we prevent conflicts and the server from crashing.

When you use res.download express will send the file to the user and as expected the HTTP request would comes to an end and you can't send any more responses. yet in the callback you are trying to send a success response
res.status(200).json({ statusCode: 200, message: 'Request Template downloaded successfully', data: null });
well this throws an error since you can't send a response since it was already sent by res.download
to fix simply remove the success response
const getRequestTemplate = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        // Call the service function to get the file path
        const filePath = await getRequestTemplateService();
        
        // Send the file as a response
        res.download(filePath, 'requestTemplate.xlsx', (err) => {
            if (err) {
                // Handle errors here
                console.error('Error downloading file:', err);
                
            } else {
                // file sent
                console.log('File downloaded successfully');
            }
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error:', error);
        res.status(500).json({ statusCode: 500, message: 'Error Downloading Request Template', data: null });
    }

}
